# Rendering collada .dae mesh gives transparent surfaces

Tags: collada

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

[image: image description]

I'm not able to figure out why the rendering does not consider hidden surfaces. Any suggestions on how I can get it fixed?
Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/13490/rendering-collada-.dae-mesh-gives-transparent-surfaces/) by [webvenky](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1202/webvenky/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 23 on 2016-06-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2016-06-01**:
The normals on your mesh may be incorrect. You can recalculate them in blender.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Yes.. You were right nkoenig. The normals were flipped. I corrected it using blender. It works fine now. Thanks a lot!

---

Originally posted by [webvenky](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1202/webvenky/) with karma: 23 on 2016-06-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0